# How to open Firefox's "Page Info" modal from a webextension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

Hitting ctrl+I or cmd+I opens up a "Page Info" modal with lots of useful information about the currently viewed page.

Is there any way to open that modal programmatically from a webextension?

Comment: No that's not possible.

Comment: Gotcha, oh well.